# How do arrows work against Lava Children?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

[Lava children](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/lava-child-TOHC) have metal immunity meaning all metal passes through them and they straight up ignore metal.  How would arrows work against them?

Answer (score 10):

**As per rules as written (and probably intended), metal-tipped arrows shouldn't do damage to Lava Children. If you wish to stick to the rules, @mxyzplk's answer is perfectly valid.**

Logically speaking, however, metal-tipped arrows should still deal damage to Lava Children, just as a tip-less arrow would still hurt a normal human being. The rules do not exactly support this, but it's definitely not as black and white as it seems. Since a DM has the final say over the published rules, I submit the following arguments for your consideration, in the event that you would like to allow arrows to deal some damage to the Lava Children.

- **An arrow's damaging ability is not solely granted by its tip.** If that were the case, short and long bows would deal the same amount of damage, provided they use the same arrowheads. An arrow's power mostly comes from the kinetic energy transferred from the bow, which is, in game terms, represented by larger bows dealing more damage.
- **Specifically, the arrowhead determines the arrow's damage *type***. All arrows for a specific bow will deal the same amount of damage, but certain specialty arrows can alter its piercing nature and change it to something else (such as the blunt arrow, which deals bludgeoning damage).
- **An arrow without a tip is not as blunt as you'd think.** [Typical medieval European arrowheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead#/media/File:Cr%C3%A9cy-en-Ponthieu_24-09-2008_12-11-33.JPG) were essentially sleeves that were set onto a sharpened piece of wood. While you can't expect "blunt" tip-less arrows to have the same penetrating power as metal tipped ones, it's seems very logical to me that getting hit with a high velocity flying piece of wood should hurt a bit.

Here's how I'd translate this into game terms if I were to allow "tip-less" arrows to deal damage to Lava Children :

1. **There is no penalty to the attack roll.** The arrow is behaving exactly as the shooter would expect, and as such wouldn't really affect his accuracy.
2. **The arrow would still do piercing damage.** Because it's not as good as a metal arrowhead does not mean it does blunt damage. That would require a specially crafted arrow, which this is not.
3. **The arrow should deal less damage.** There has to be a penalty somewhere. Just as I'd allow a player wielding a spear (1d8 piercing) to attack a Lava Children as if he was wielding a quarterstaff (1d6 bludgeoning), I'd allow arrows to deal reduced damage, maybe 1d3 for shortbows and 1d4 for longbows.

Comment: Yes, calling an untipped arrow a 'bludgeoning' instrument is roughly akin to calling a sharpened, but used, pencil the same.

Answer (score 1):

Given that an untipped arrow will still penetrate a target, there's no reason a metal-tipped, wood-shafted arrow wouldn't have any effect on something that is immune to metal, *especially* since the metal itself passes through harmlessly.  The total mass and velocity of the arrow is unchanged in this scenario, so it will be imparting the same energy/force on the target, just in a slightly different manner.

An untipped arrow will not stabilize as well as a tipped arrow, however, against a lava child, the metal tip would exist, but have no effect on the target, essentially leaving a perfectly balanced and well-stabilized wooden shaft embedded in said target every bit as deeply as normal.

Since your typical medieval combat arrow is tipped with a bodkin point, which are designed solely for penetration rather than cutting, it's also unlikely that the damage would be significantly reduced.  Perhaps slightly, due to the reduced diameter of the shaft as compared to the tip, but the minor decrease in diameter is unlikely to significantly impact the effect of an otherwise identical shot.

Answer (score 0):

Arrows would do no damage.

Arrows (unless specially made) get their damaging ability from their metal tip. So it's like shooting a headless arrow (aka a dowel rod) - ouchy, but not especially damaging. Unless the arrows are [pure wood](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/ammunition-bow-thorn) or [obsidian-tipped](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Obsidian) or something, but normal metal-tipped arrows have no effect. If you are feeling generous you could have them treated as [blunt arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/ammunition-bow-arrow-blunt), doing nonlethal damage with a -4 to hit.

Answer (score -2):

Regular arrows would deal no damage, you'd have to have some kind of primative stone-tipped arrow, or perhaps some other material like crystal to get through their Metal Immunity.

A list of all special materials can be found [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials)

Crystalline arrows happen to ignore part or all of armor bonuses depending on the type of crystal, so they're quite useful and not ridiculously expensive to acquire.

Blood Crystal is also a useful type of arrow, as it causes targets hit by it to bleed.

Also, its likely that they would be vulnerable to Glassteel as well since it's simply glass that has been given the strength and hardness of steel.

Comment: An untipped arrow will still penetrate a target quite well, so there's no reason why it wouldn't deal damage.

Comment: A dowel rod will not penetrate a person if fired from a bow. It might bounce and cause a welt, but it will not penetrate because it is not sharp.

Comment: A 2x4 will penetrate a person if launched with sufficient force.  An untipped arrow will easily do the same.  Behind the tip, the shaft is typically sharpened to the same sort of point that you'd see on a well-used #2 pencil, but an flat-chopped shaft launched from a bow will still penetrate a person, unless you're talking about a *very* low-poundage bow, such as one typically sold with suction-cup arrows.  The problem with un-tipped arrows isn't that they're not capable of penetrating anything, it's that they aren't particularly *stable*, so they tend to fly wild.